# How to automatically get branches for "Branches to merge" dialog?

Tags: git, merge, phpstorm

In PhpStorm Git -> Pull dialog I always have to click on reload button, and click on checkbox next to the relevant remote branch.

Just statistically, out of 100 pulls, a at least a few times I misclick on an incorrect branch and pull an incorrect remote branch. Some confusing situations happen.

So, I would like to know how to specify a default branch to pull, and to make it pull remote branches automatically. Obviously, for "master" it should be "master" from the default remote.
By the way, default remote I did succeed to specify by editing local repository config and specifying `remote` under `[branch "..."]` section.

PhpStorm's documentation is way too basic on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the way to avoid that in `CSV` -> `Pull` but [you can also pull changes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/update-project-dialog-git.html) with `VCS` -> `Update Project` and check `Do not show this dialog in the future`.